Unable to use Selenium with ProxyScrape proxy server that requires manual login
I'm trying to use Selenium to open a browser and navigate to a website using a ProxyScrape proxy server. However, I'm encountering an issue where the browser requires me to manually log in to the proxy server, even though I've provided the username and password in the code.
Here's the code I'm using:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"
proxy = f"{username}:{password}@<ip:port>"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("http://www.example.com")

input("Press Enter to close the browser...")


What I tried:
I ran the code above using Selenium version 4.1.0 and Chrome version 96.0.4664.45 on Windows 10. I expected the browser to open and navigate to the website using the provided proxy server and credentials, without requiring manual login.
What I expected:
I expected the browser to open and navigate to the website using the provided proxy server and credentials, without requiring manual login.
What actually resulted:
When I ran the code, the browser opened and I was prompted to log in to the proxy server. I entered the provided username and password, and the login process was successful. However, I'm unable to automate the login process using the code, and I'm still prompted to log in again when I try to navigate to a website. I tried using both HTTP and HTTPS URLs for the website, but I still encountered the same issue.
I'm not sure why the browser is requiring me to manually log in to the proxy server, even though I've provided the username and password in the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

good question.  some websites detect automation tools. this could be one.
